# Extract a list of Transferable from a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker

The [**postMessage()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) method of the Worker interface allows to pass a `transferList` which is an array of objects whose references should be passed (rather than the objects being copied).

```
myWorker.postMessage(aMessage, transferList);
```

Is there a safe way to recursively extract all objects that can have their references passed (according to the API, only [MessagePort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort) and [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)), so we don't have to worry about passing all of them manually?

```
myWorker.postMessage(aMessage, extractTransferList(aMessage));
```

Is it recommended to implement this behavior?

**Example**:

When we consider the following code:

```
var objData =
{
    str: "string",
    i8: new Int8Array(200),
    obj : {
       num : 8,
       ab: new ArrayBuffer(100)
    }  
};
objWorker.postMessage(objData, [objData.i8.buffer, objData.obj.ab]);
```

We need to specify in the second parameter all fields of our objects that should have their references passed. My question is about building a function that does the job for us, to make sure that we don't forget some transferable objects here (that could impact performances without us knowing it).

```
objWorker.postMessage(objData, extractTransferList(objData));
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"so we don't have to worry about passing all of them manually"*? (Also: `canvas` references can be passed to web workers.) Also, what's the question? Is it *"Is there a safe way to recursively extract..."* or is it *"Is it recommended to implement..."*? (Those are **different** questions.)

Comment: Note: "pass by reference" is a specific term of art that doesn't apply here. What you mean here is that references to the objects are passed to the web worker rather than copies of them.

Comment: I added an example to make it more clear. BTW: thank you for correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is about building a function that does the job for us, to make sure that we don't forget some transferable objects here (that could impact performances without us knowing it).

You could implement a function that recurses through the object graph looking for transferrable objects and builds an array of them, e.g.:

```
// *Sketch*, not debugged code!!
function getTransferrables(obj, array) {
    var key, value;
    if (!array) {
        array = [];
    }
    for (key in obj) {
        // (Add a hasOwnProperty check here if you want one)
        value = obj[key];
        if (value !== null) {
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                if (isTransferrable(value)) {
                    array.push(value);
                } else { // I *think* you want an else here, or should we recurse into transferrables?
                    getTransferrables(value, array);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
function isTransferrable(obj) {
    switch (toString.call(obj)) {
        case "[object MessagePort]": // I checked these on Chrome and Firefox,
        case "[object Int8Array]":   // you'll want to verify on your target
        case "[object Int16Array]":  // browsers!
        // ...etc...
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Then you'd use  `getTransferrables` like this:

```
foo.postMessage(obj, getTransferrables(obj));
```

If you find that the `toString` trick in `isTransferrable` isn't reliable cross-browser, you can use the `constructor` property of the object instead, e.g.:

```
var ctor = obj.constructor;
return ctor === MessagePort ||
       ctor === Int8Array ||
       ctor === Int16Array ||
       // ...
       ;
```

You'll have to check which (if either) is more reliable, and possibly even have to mix the two to get good cross-browser coverage.

You'll note I haven't used `instanceof` in `isTransferrable`, which would seem like it would be useful. The problem is that typed arrays are *subclassable* in ES2015:

```
class MyNiftyArray extends Int32Array {
    // ...
}
```

and when you do that, instances of `MyNiftyArray` are `instanceof` the base class:

```
let a = new MyNiftyArray();
console.log(a instanceof Int32Array); // true
```

...but we don't know that the subclass instance is, in fact, transferrable.

**However**, if you're only using this stuff with your own code, and you know you never subclass a tranferrable type, you could indeed use `instanceof`.

```
// Relies on knowing that `obj` is not an instance of a subclass of a
// tranferrable
function isTransferrable(obj) {
    return obj instanceof MessagePort ||
           obj instanceof Int8Array ||
           obj instanceof Int16Array ||
           // ...
           ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's kind of what i had in mind. But is it safe (since it's not the default behavior)? Or maybe the `postMessage()` function was designed with a list as second parameter because Transferable objects become _neutered_ in the context they were sent from? It seems that there some lack of definition on this term in the API.

Comment: @Sebastien: Well, provided you test that your `isTransferrable` is okay, it should be safe **provided** you really want to transfer all the transferrable objects. Re "neuter," it seems [pretty clear to me](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-transferable-neutered): *"...and will permanently neuter the original object. (This is an irreversible and non-idempotent operation; once an object has been transferred, it cannot be transferred, or indeed used, again.)"*

Comment: We can also use the instanceof keyword in the `isTransferable()` function. If i'm not wrong, that should be a more reliable cross-browser solution.

Comment: @Sebastien: In the *general* case, it would be less reliable, actually: Typed arrays are subclassable, and if you subclass a typed array, instances of the subclass are `instanceof` the typed array. But we don't know that they're transferrable. I should have said why I didn't use it. (And now I have. :-) ) Of course, it would be fine if you're only working with your own code and know you didn't do that.

Comment: Thank you for the complete and accurate answer!

Comment: Last and final comment about your proposal: all typed array (like Int16Array) should contain an ArrayBuffer which is transferable (a field named `buffer` if i remember correctly). Since `getTransferable()` is recursive, i think that we don't need to test for all thoses types, but only for `ArrayBuffer` and `MessagePort`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to find every transferable:

```js
class Dummy {}

export function findTransferable(obj) {
  const transferable = new Set()
  const objsToSearch = [obj]
  function checkForTransferable(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'object' || value === null) return
    if (ArrayBuffer.isView(value)) {
      transferable.add(value.buffer) // ArrayBuffer
    } else if (
         value instanceof ArrayBuffer
      || value instanceof MessagePort
      || value instanceof ImageBitmap
      || value instanceof OffscreenCanvas
      || value instanceof ReadableStream
      || value instanceof WritableStream
      || value instanceof TransformStream
      || value instanceof (globalThis.AudioData || Dummy)
      || value instanceof (globalThis.VideoFrame || Dummy)
      || value instanceof (globalThis.RTCDataChannel || Dummy)
      || value instanceof (globalThis.WebTransportSendStream || Dummy)
      || value instanceof (globalThis.WebTransportReceiveStream || Dummy)
    ) {
      transferable.add(value)
    } else objsToSearch.push(value)
  }
  while (objsToSearch.length) {
    const obj = objsToSearch.pop()
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      obj.forEach(checkForTransferable)
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
      if (typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
        [...obj.values(obj)].forEach(checkForTransferable)
      } else {
        Object.values(obj).forEach(checkForTransferable)
      }
    }
  }
  if (transferable.size) {
    // console.log(transferable)
    return [...transferable]
  }
  return
}
```